# Does deleting the interfaces config file reset ifconfig to default (DHCP)

Tags: networking, server

Okay, so I have a remote Ubuntu Server (14.04). Yesterday, I tried changing some network configs in /etc/network/interfaces ... Yeah ... You get the picture ... Now I can't remote into it.

I do however have someone at that location, who could change the configs for me ... My 12 year old little sister (Yep, that's a better option than asking my mum) ...

I was thinking of the easiest way that I could explain to her, which will allow me to gain access to my server again. If I got her to `rm /etc/network/interfaces`, and then restart the server, would it automatically create a default one, and in turn get an IP from DHCP?

Also, if anyone has any other suggestions on how I can gain access, I'd be glad to hear :D (I do have access to another server on the same network)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK rebooting will not create a new default /etc/network/interfaces file. Assuming your default interface name is `eth0` you should have her create or edit it manually as

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

If you are not sure about the interface naming convention, have her run `ifconfig` or `ls /sys/class/net` to identify the correct name.

Comment: I was afraid of that ... Hmm ... I know that it's bond0 I need to configure ... So I guess it's just a matter of hoping she'll do it right (Or at least better than I did Lol)

Comment: Ha ... After all that, it was just stuck on the GRUB boot menu ... Strange ... I have something else to look into now ... Thanks anyways :D